# SwiftUI macOS currencyFormatter does not update binding variable

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have an ActionSheet with one Textfield in it. Since this Textfield hast the formatter() attribute it does not update the binding variable hourly. If I press the OK Button the value of hourly is still 0. If there is another Textfield and I click into this and then press the OK Button the value of hourly is correct. But I have just one Textfield in this Sheet.

Is there a way to keep the value of the binding variable updated?

```
struct AddClientSheet: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var hourly = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text(“Kunde hinzufügen”).font(.title)) {
                TextField(“Stundenrate”, value: $hourly, formatter: currencyFormatter())
            }
            Divider()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: cancel) {
                    Text("Abbrechen")
                }
                Button(action: addClient) {
                    Text("Hinzufügen")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func currencyFormatter() -> NumberFormatter {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.numberStyle = .currency
        return f
    }

    func addClient() {
        if hourly > 0{
            //store the data
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }

    func cancel() {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am working on a macOS application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work (tested with Xcode 11.2 / macOS 10.15.3)

```
func addClient() {
    NSApp.keyWindow?.makeFirstResponder(nil) // finish text edit
    if hourly > 0 {
        //store the data
        print(">> hourly = \(hourly)")
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```